# Updated my latptop cpu from i3 to i7. Experiencing random system hangs and segfaults

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, segmentation-fault

I have 
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Acer-Aspire-V3-771G-17-3-inch-Laptop/dp/B009R15O40

I've upgraded it over the years (bought new 16gb memory, new ssd). Now I realized it's too slow for me, and decided to upgrade CPU.

I've found a configuration with better cpu
[https://www.amazon.com/Acer-Aspire-V3-771G-9809-17-3-Inch-Laptop/dp/B009JXJWZI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009JXJWZI)
to ensure compatibility and bought its cpu from the local craigslist.

Now I experience random segfaults (programs crash, system wouldn't boot sometimes). If I have only one RAM (normally it's two of them), segfaults starting to occur less frequently (at least I can boot).

I have Linux Mint 18.1, with 4.4.0 kernel.

Anything I can do about it?

Comment: No; Laptops are not designed to have their CPU upgraded, your crashes, are likely connected to your upgrade

Comment: It somehow stable on the one specific RAM card on one specific slot. I'll try to update BIOS later, it's 2.07 against the latest 2.28, maybe it will fix things. 
I didn't really have much choice, it's either that, or new laptop, and I don't have enough money for new laptop now.